# regex for extract number after word in a file with python

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file with the number of testcases passed and failed like below

```
****Tests Passed:   20
****Tests Failed:    4
```

I want to capture the number for passed and failed and write it to another file which is tab separated

I Have tried the regular expression below but it only gives passed number although script reads all the lines of the file, help would be much appreciated.

```
"Tests Passed:     (\d+)"
"Tests Failed:     (\d+)"
```

Comment: Try `.*Passed: ([0-9]{1,}).*Failed: ([0-9]{1,}).*`

Answer (score 1):

The number of spaces is variable, use `\s*` for 0 or more spaces:

```
"Tests Passed:\s*(\d+)"
"Tests Failed:\s*(\d+)"
```